# Shortcut for hyperlink in Overleaf

Tags: overleaf

Is there a shortcut in Overleaf for hyperlinks? For instance, when selected a text, command + b bolds the text. I was wondering if there is a shortcut for hyperlink as well, so that when I select a text, it automatically generates \href{}{selected text}.

Comment: there is a show hotkeys item in the left sidebar menu, which shows [these keys](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RYaZ1.png)  so no nothing for hyperref commands.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, not enough reputation to comment.

Based on their extended list of keyboard shortcuts [here](https://v1.overleaf.com/latex/templates/overleaf-keyboard-shortcuts/qykqfvmxdnjf.pdf) I don't see anything referring to a link.
You can see all available commands by pressing F1 inside Overleaf.